# Netlify/Craco Failed to load config "react-app" to extend from. Referenced from: /opt/build/repo/package.json

Tags: reactjs, web-deployment, netlify, craco

https://hastebin.com/ijaxewevaw.yaml 
Here are the logs

Build command: `craco build` 
NODE_VERSION: 14.17.6

My package.json: https://hastebin.com/evorodesay.json

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add `eslint-config-react-app` in your dev dependencies, you can add it using yarn like `yarn add -D eslint-config-react-app` or npm `npm install --save-dev eslint-config-react-app`